# display data in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i want to display data in Gridview in a format like in the image.

any ideas folks?

[image]

the datas in table is stored in this way

```
Qsn1    A train running at the speed of 60 km/hr crosses a pole in 9 seconds. What is the length of the train?  Option1 150 metres  5   
Qsn1    A train running at the speed of 60 km/hr crosses a pole in 9 seconds. What is the length of the train?  Option1 152 metres  5   
Qsn1    A train running at the speed of 60 km/hr crosses a pole in 9 seconds. What is the length of the train?  Option1 154 metres  5   
Qsn1    A train running at the speed of 60 km/hr crosses a pole in 9 seconds. What is the length of the train?  Option1 155 metres  5
```

thank you

Comment: Can you post the solution as an answer if you found one?  It might help others who run into a similar problem.

Comment: i am not using the above pattern, i have changed everything.. thats the reason

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the repeater control to do that..

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) to repeater page [original link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using **Repeater** contorl over GridView Will give you more control over formating your output.

Answer (score 0):

ASPX

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("Question") %>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rbl1" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="QuestionID"></asp:RadioButtonList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Code

```
gv1.RowDataBound += (s, ev) =>
                    {
                        if (ev.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                        {
                            var rbl1 = (ListControl)ev.Row.FindControl("rbl1");
                            rbl1.DataSource = ((QuestionEntity)ev.Row.DataItem).Answers;
                            rbl1.DataBind();
                        }
                    };
```

Comment: thank you  Magnus.if this questionEntity comes with linq? i am working with vs2005.

Comment: The QuestionEntity was just an example, could be anything. For example a DataRow if you bind the GridView using a DataTable. But you can create your own QuestionEntity class with an IEnumerable Answers property, and return that from a Linq query.