# is their any option to move data from database in click event of button in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net

Hi
I am displaying one question & their 4 options per page.
For that i have one label for question & radiobuttonlist for their answers.There is next button. after clicking next button i want to display another record.
I have tried this with dataset with random function, but its not proper. values gets repeated. so i want first record to be display in pageload & after clicking next button next record should move till record exists.
I want to move one record to another after clicking next button.
how i can do this?
asp.net, c#
Thank you.

Comment: Could you please explain your exact need. Where you are displaying the data?

Comment: i am using dataset for fetching the data.i have to display one question & their answers . After clicking next button it sholud display another record from database

Comment: Please edit your question to add more detail about what you're trying to do and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use any of the data controls like gridview, repeater or datalist and keep the paging property on.

Comment: i am using one label for question & radiobuttonlist for answers. i used random function but values are repeating. so i want data one by one from database till record exists

Comment: See the thread and it explains what exactly you need - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509765/display-data-in-gridview